# Android ListView background image optimisation

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, drawable

I've run into a problem, the problem is that I have a `ListView` and I want to set a background image on that `ListView`. I managed to achieve this using the `background` attribute in `XML` and set the `cacheColorHint` to `#00000000`.

If I make the `cacheColorHint` to transparent color like above, the scrolling performance drops significantly. On Android smartphones my `ListView` is working good but on Android Tablet the `ListView` is moving very slow.

The image I use as a `Drawable` has the size about 500x800px (the one for Tablets), the one for phones is smaller. Iv'e tried also to set a smaller image(like the one for phones) but it's the same.

My image has only a logo at the bottom of the screen having about 100px `height` and the rest is a white color.

Does anybody know how I can make the `ListView` work properly or at least better?

Thank you!

Comment: Usually I use the ListView inside an layout and add the background to the layout and set the listview background and color hint to transparent.

Comment: I did that too but no results.. thank's anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, aside from the obvious solution of *not* using an image as the background, you've done everything you can to [optimize](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/listview-backgrounds.html) the `ListView`.  One thing you could try is to set the `cacheColorHint` to the most **dominant** color in the image.

What I mean by that is, looking at the *book* example from the previous link, you could set the `cacheColorHint` color to some sort of an orange which would result in your scrolling operations being *a lot* less expensive, compared to when set to transparent (`#00000000`).

Comment: Thank you for your hint.. I read that page too but I hoped that maybe somebody managed to make a workaround..

Answer (score 1):

I managed to optimize the speed of the ListView by cutting the white color off and setting the logo image onto a ImageView.

Here is my XML now:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
          android:background="@color/white">

<ImageView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scaleType="fitXY"
           android:src="@drawable/background_img" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

<ListView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
       android:smoothScrollbar="true" android:scrollingCache="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Her is what you are looking to implement:

LayerDrawable-
A Drawable that manages an array of other Drawables. These are drawn in array order, so the element with the largest index will be drawn on top.

OR

use Frame layout to achieve desired affect.
http://tinyurl.com/82ycrpd